# Google script onEdit in all pasted cells

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been using an oEdit function to set the actual date in the column S when I add a new carton to my inventory (ctn, in column F).

It works perfectly when I enter the references manually but when I paste few references cartons at once, the script only works on the first edited row.

How do I manage execute the script for all the pasted rows?

Please find following the script:

```
function onEdit(ctn) {

var sheet = ctn.source.getActiveSheet();
var added_ctn = ctn.range;
var date_add = sheet.getRange("S" + added_ctn.getRow());

if (sheet.getName() !== 'SORTIE CENTRALE VERS AUBER'
    || added_ctn.columnStart != 6)        
    {return}

    date_add.setValue(new Date());

}
```

Comment: Your code only does one line (```added_ctn.getRow()```). You should do a loop for all the rows in the range. Check the [getHeight](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getheight) or the [getLastRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow) methods. Both should help you discover the number of affected rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! I will work on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something this perhaps?

```
function onEditxx(e) 
{
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() !== 'SORTIE CENTRALE VERS AUBER'|| e.range.getColumn() != 6)
  {
    return;
  }
  for(var i=0;i<e.range.getNumRows();i++)
  {
    var offset=e.range.getRow() + i;
    sheet.getRange('S'+ offset).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks a lot. Unfortunately the result is the same. It put the date only in the first pasted row. I keep trying :)

Comment: I was using too much of your code the first time.  There is no columnStart for ranges. But I still have to assume that you want to put it in column S.  By the way range.getRow() always returns the row of the upper left corner.

Comment: Yes indeed, it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for the information, I get more understanding now :).