# How do you autofill Current Date when New Data is Added to another Cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I've looked up and down everywhere around the forums and I can't believe no one has asked this and I'm sure some of you might want to know this as well.

So there definitely has been questions about auto date fill, however, almost 100% of the scripts I've found do nothing of what I am looking for, so here is the question.

**So the question**: How do you autofill a cell to current date when another cell is populated? but...
The one thing always left out...How do you get the date to fill the same amount of rows in case there are multiple cells in the same column being populated?

The problem that I'm getting, is when I'm at work trying to create some spreadsheets, is this date issue. I want to be able to take a batch of data, populate a cell or any cell that I want to designate the script to and not have column A only populate one date for a batch of data. There is many information I have to paste into a sheet and I don't want to have to manually populate each cell in Column A to the current date.

Here is my script, please let me know what I can do to modify this .
My columns that I am working this script into is Column A for the date, and I am populating Column E.

Sample images:
[image]

```html
var COLUMNTOCHECK = 5;
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,-4];
var SHEETNAME = 'Appraisers'

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Research ```e```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with your code, per se. It works just fine. But as @TheMaster says, you should read up on the `e` variable in the OnEdit trigger, since it returns a number of ["event objects"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite) and these are described in detail in the [Trigger documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).

This is worthwhile because you would have known that `OnEdit` works when you **edit** data, and not when you copy/paste. But there is a workaround.

The `e.range` object will tell you the range in which the copy/paste took place. You can test it by running a simple logger command:
 `Logger.log("e range = "+e.range.getA1Notation());`
By using that range, we can calculate the start row and number of rows in the range, so a loop can create the offset value.

Try this code.

Due credit to Cooper in [Google script onEdit in all pasted cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755440/google-script-onedit-in-all-pasted-cells)

```
function so_53471920(e) {

    // set up the spreadsheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    // set up some key variables
    var COLUMNTOCHECK = 5;
    var DATETIMELOCATION = [0, -4];
    var SHEETNAME = "Appraisers";
    var adjustdate = new(Date);

    // return the edited range from OnEdit
    var myrange = e.range;
    // get the starting row, starting column, range depth in the range and name of the active sheet
    var startRow = e.range.getRow();
    var startColumn = e.range.getColumn();
    var rowdepth = e.range.getNumRows();
    var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
    // Logger.log("1=e.range = "+e.range.getA1Notation());// DEBUG
    // Logger.log("2=starting column in e.range = "+startColumn);// DEBUG
    // Logger.log("3=starting row in e.range = "+startRow);// DEBUG
    // Logger.log("4=Number of rows in e.range = "+rowdepth);// DEBUG
    // Logger.log("5=The sheet name is "+activeSheet);

    // test the sheet and column
    // Note: getColumn returns the starting column position for this range; so this works only if the left hand paste column is "E"
    if (activeSheet !== SHEETNAME || startColumn !== COLUMNTOCHECK) {
        // quit if this isn't the right sheet or column
        Logger.log("system quit");
        return;
    } else {
        // loop through the number of rows in the pasted range
        // getNumRows returns the number of rows in this range.
        //Logger.log("start row="+startRow+", target i = "+(startRow+rowdepth)); //DEBUG
        for (var i = startRow; i < (startRow + rowdepth); i++) {
            // i = the row number
            // Logger.log("Updated row A"+i);//DFEBUG
            e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange("A" + i).setValue(adjustdate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, much is appreciated. However, it's still not working. I did some further research and I must add, that I am not the most competent coder in G-sheets but I am aggressively learning and doing my best to understand.
I've copied and pasted the code, and tried adding data in column 'E', and now no date appears in Column 'A' compared to the last code I developed.

What should I be checking for and is there any part of the code I need to change?
Thank you!

Comment: Please let me know if sharing my worksheet will help you out further in order to let me know what I've been doing incorrectly with this new code, I'd like to learn from this as much as possible.

Comment: @FeatherDuster **Did you set an OnEdit trigger for this function?** That is the most likely reason that it wouldn't be working. You can also uncomment the "Logger.log" lines and they'll show you the progress of the script and the relevant values; this will help track down where and why the script stops working. By all means, share your worksheet; this would have been good at the outset too.

Comment: Hey Tedinoz, you are correct, I added the OnEdit trigger and that did it, I need to make sure to look out for those things. Thank you very much for your support on this and I want to make sure I share this code with anyone else around here that might be looking for the same thing to learn from.

Comment: So I ran into a problem pertaining to this autodate function. So I'm using the script that I made to auto timestamp when a Team Member assigns their name and the 'Date' (Column 'B') portion timestamps correctly upon doing so.The problem now is that the new script provided by you, is not working along side my script. When Column 'E' (Vendor ID) is populated with new data, Column 'A' (Date of New Data) does not want to populate with the current date. This was originally working when I deleted my script just to test out the function provided from this thread.

Comment: Here is a link to my worksheet, I'll give you permissions once I notice you are trying to enter into it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-0PjMFl7tTRBg6f2Li5LmLKzJxhc9VYqH62rx16Ccl4/edit#gid=1265106835